# Hiding a div on IMDB search

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey, imdb

Since IMDB search can't exclude specific genres, I would like to hide the ones who I am not interested in, using Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey.

Every movie is inside a class named `"lister-item mode-advanced"`:

[image: code inspector]

Inside that is:

```
<span class="genre">
Animation, Adventure, Family            </span>
```

Looking at other answers, I thought something like this could work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         NoAnimation
// @namespace    NoAnimation
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      *.imdb.com/search*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_log
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant        GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==

$("lister-item mode-advanced")  .show ()
  .has ("span.genre:contains('Animation')")
  .hide ();
```

which doesn't work of course :(

I'm doing this test on [akas.imdb.com/search/title?...](http://akas.imdb.com/search/title?genres=sci_fi&my_ratings=exclude&title_type=feature&sort=num_votes,desc).

I hope I was clear enough. Can anyone give me advice? :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
It loooks like your code snippet is not correct due to class definition absence and test data. Please try digging a bit more about that and correct information in your question - it will help answer your question

Comment: @StepanNovikov, For a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey question, a link to a public target page is the gold-standard test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake is, that is not how to specify class in a jQuery selector. It should have been `$(".lister-item.mode-advanced")`.

But there are other problems:

1. Brittle selectors used.  For example `mode-advanced` is not always present.  May not always be a span, etc.
2. Unnecessary logic (`.show()`, for example).
3. Very obsolete version of jQuery.
4. Extraneous and unhelpful meta info.

Here's a complete script that addresses these issues:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Hide Animations from IMBD search results
// @match    *://*.imdb.com/search*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.

$(".lister-item").has (".genre:contains('Animation')").hide ();
```

Comment: This solves perfectly my request of help! Thanks for your time.